# Convert two seperate columns of type org.apache.spark.sql.Column into a dataframe of two columns in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two columns of type org.apache.spark.sql.Column

I need to create a dataframe from these two columns such that the dataframe looks like [col1,col2] . Both columns contains data of double type.

Any suggestions on how to create the dataframe.

Comment: Could you provide a broader example of what you are trying to accomplish? Typically, you don't need to build a `Dataframe` from the `Column` type directly.

Comment: I agree. In my case , I am getting two columns which are associated , say x and y (group which x belongs to). I need to now form a dataframe with these two columns so that i can perform the groupby operations and more on top of it.

Comment: How are the columns associated, is it a straight join where both columns are same length, is there some degree of binning, or is there a foreign key relationship?

Comment: Its a straight join where both columns are of same length.